# Model binder which parses object from named parameters of controller action?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have following Controller action:

```cs
[FromBodyParams] // Made up attribute I should find a way to implement.
public async Task<something> Accounts(int businessId, int someparam, ListingSettings settings = null)
{
    // ...
}
```

I want to parse the parameters *from the body* of request in format:

```
{
     "businessId" : 5,
     "someparam" : 9,
     "settings" : {  }
}
```

Only way I can do it now is to use `[FromBody]` parameter attribute, which only works for *one* parameter and requires me to wrap all arguments in a new class.

This is not a convinient way, I'm trying to implement my own controller action attribute that parses directly from the body of the request in format above.

How I could implement model binder / new attribute that parses from the body using action parameters as keys?